# SSIS Logging Throws an Error

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2008, logging, ssis

I have programmed some ETL which works OK, the processing finishes without errors. Now I want to create a log using SSIS Loggin feature.

However, once I set this logging up (SSIS log provider for SQL Server; all events; all cotainers are checked, also the log is checked) and start the ETL, the MS Visual Studio 2008 app return error window with not error specified in it so I don't have even clue what could be the problem. The destination of ETL is SQL Server 2008 R2. The credentials are the same as my AD account, I have no problem to write the data into this DB (respectivelly it's tables).

To sum up, the whole ETL run works without problem, but once the SSIS Logging is turned on, the ETL does not even start.

One notice: the log table was created in the DB though [domain\user_name].[sysssislog]. Also the logging to e.g. text file works without any problems.

Any suggestions, please?

**+++**

**Error I am receiving**

TITLE: Package Validation Error

---

Package Validation Error

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Error at Reporting_v3 [Log provider "SSIS log provider for SQL Server"]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E14.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80040E14  Description: "There is already an object named 'sysssislog' in the database.".

Error at Reporting_v3 [Log provider "SSIS log provider for SQL Server"]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E14.

There is like around 500 rows with the same error. If I delete the ssislog table and run the package with SSIS Logging turned on, the table is created again and the same error pops up.

Comment: How do you set the DB Connection String for your ETL and for you logging Provider? Is it a hard-coded value or are you reading from config and dynamically setting it?

Comment: The connection setting is set up as SQL Server Native Client 10.0 as provider, servername, using window authentication and the database I want select. Please check the error I am receiving in my updated question.

Comment: "the log table was created in the DB though [domain\user_name].[sysssislog]" - Does this mean that the table was manually created earlier?

Comment: Not at all .. it's being created automatically by the BIDS itself ..

Comment: I see. So if I understand correctly, if you drop the dbo.sysssislog table and then run your ETL, the table dbo.sysssislog gets recreated, but you also get an error and no records are written?

Comment: Exactly. The only thing - it's not created as dbo.sysssislog but  [domain\user_name].[sysssislog]. Other tables of mine are as [user_name]\[table_name].

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37322/discussion-between-shree-pat18-and-dnac)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. The solution can be found at the following link:

http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/467794/ssis-log-provider-for-sql-server-do-not-work-when-default-schema-is-not-dbo-sysdtslog90-sysssislog

Answer (score 0):

> There is already an object named 'sysssislog' in the database

I got the same error. The problem was I didn't have dbo permission to create system tables and stored procedures.

So it would create the sysssislog table under my user name:

```
 DOMAIN\user.sysssislog
```

and not

```
 System Tables dbo.sysssislog
```

It also creates a stored procedure `sp_ssis_addlogentry` under normal stored procedures instead of system stored procedures.

`sp_ssis_addlogentry` tries to insert into `dbo.sysssislog`, but can't because it doesn't exist. But the user one does so it complains object already exists.

h/t to vikas ojha

https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/error-with-ssis-log-provider-for-sql-server-possible-bug#post-713527